# What is the best way to do cachebusting in chrome, (best if there is something which can help me clear cache when dev tool is open)

Tags: google-chrome

I am doing asp.net mvc web-programming and chrome make pain in my development. it cache everything that's running on asp.net mvc's running localhost port.

I have a half dozen stylesheet having 5k lines of code. if I change something it's not taking changes.

it's frustrating to do too many refresh to get it updated. I have tried web-essentials and some other mads kristensen's plugin but that's only work if I make change it's showing me the updated but it's old if I refresh.

anyone have any plugin, settings to tell chrome to stop caching my localhost port or do not cache. I can run a seprate profile if there is some settings that can be applied to whole profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force a refresh of all resources, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>.

To make it automatic while developer tools are open, activate the "Disable cache" option in the Network tool.

[image]